# Post request com retrofit + android

Tags: android, retrofit

Estou estudando android, e estou tentando usar a biblioteca retrofit com android. Após ler a documentação e ver diversos exemplos em respostas aqui no stackoverflow consegui fazer envio de dados de um formulário via `POST` para uma página escrita em php e receber o retorno (em formato `JSON`), porém não consigo receber todos os objetos, recebo só o primeiro, consigo receber todos os dados se usar `GET`, mas não se eu usar `POST`, alguém saberia informar se isso é possível usando `POST`, no caso receber vários objetos, só tenho visto exemplos com `GET`, segue meu código abaixo:

Dependências:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

MainActivity (dentro de um botão):

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.101.36/json/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

            Call<User> call = apiService.validateUser(inputEmail.getText().toString(), inputSenha.getText().toString());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    //Verifica se houve a conexão com sucesso ao webservice
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        textView.setText("ERROR onResponde: " + response.code());
                    } else {
                        //requisição retona os dados com sucesso
                        String email = response.body().getEmail();
                        String senha = response.body().getPassword();
                        textView.append("email: " + email + " - senha: " + senha + "\n");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    textView.setText(t.getMessage());
                }

            });
```

Interface:

```
public interface ApiService {
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("index.php") 
   Call<User> validateUser(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("password") String password
   );
}
```

Classe User:

```
public class User {
private int id;
private String error, error_msg, username, email, password;

public String getError(){
    return this.error;
}

public String getError_msg(){
    return this.error_msg;
}

public int getId(){
    return this.id;
}

public String getUsername(){
    return this.username;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return this.email;
}
```

}

Index.php:

```
$email = $_POST['username'];

$senha = $_POST['password'];

echo '
{
"email":"'.$email.'",
"password":"'.$senha.'"
},
{
"email":"'.$email.'",
"password":"'.$senha.'"
},
{
"email":"joselito@joselito.com",
"password":"123456"
}
';
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com todos os dados? Você pode postar um exemplo de resposta, e apontar o que não consegue ler.

Comment: Veja a imagem: http://www.neoprime.com.br/Screenshot_2016-09-26-17-42-10.png

No arquivo index.php há 3 objetos, mas retona apenas 1.

Tentei fazer uma lista dos dados, mas não consegui implementar a passagem dos parâmetros.
Só conseguir implementar com GET, ai sim consigo retornar todos os objetos, mas quero passar os meus dados via POST e não via GET.

Ex: quero passar o token via POST e receber os dados do usuário na requisição.

Comment: Resolvido:

Para futuras consultas, segue o link da solução: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724751/how-get-list-of-objects-with-post-request-to-retrofit-2-1-0-with-android

Comment: tenta isso.... echo "
[{
'email':'$email',
'password':'$senha'
},
{
'email':'$email',
'password':'$senha'
},
{
'email':'joselito@joselito.com',
'password':'123456'
}]
";